# Android SQLite INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-insert

i am getting this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":12": syntax error (code 1): while compiling: INSERT INTO TIME VALUES(15:12);
```

my code is below:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("timedb", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
            s = (timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString() +" : " + timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString());
            s = "'" + s + "'";


            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists TIME"+" ("+ "times" +" VARCHAR(100)"+");");
            query = "INSERT INTO TIME"+ "VALUES"+"("+s+")";
            db.execSQL(query);
            startActivity(new Intent(Preferences.this, MainActivity.class));
```

I'm sure, that i am getting error from this piece of code. Can someone help me?

Comment: Sanitize before you insert. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Try this: `query = "INSERT INTO TIME"+ "VALUES"+"('"+s+"')";`

Comment: Add single quote to your value as it is String.

Comment: Not only you need **single quotes**, as already noted. You also miss a **space** before the VALUES keyword: `"INSERT INTO TIME VALUES ('" + s + "')"`. You also want to get rid of useless string concatenations, wherever possible.

Comment: before asked question at least search on _Google_ **how to play with SQLite in Android?** you'll get 100 ways. i'm damn sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed single quotes while passing value to query

Try following it may help you

```
query = "INSERT INTO TIME"+ " VALUES "+"('"+s+"')";
```